# display command not working in command line

Tags: display, debian, terminal

I am running debian v10.0 on a raspberry pi. I have a directory of pictures with jpg, png and jpeg extensions. When I try to use `display image.extension` on any of them I get the error

`display-im6.q16: unable to open x server @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/433`

`display --verion` returns

`Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16`

If I run `startx` into the GUI, I can right-click and open the images in both imageViewer and imageMagick.

How do I use `display` to view these images while in the command line?

Comment: you have to have X running for a program that uses X to work

Comment: How do you expect images to be rendered in the command line? With colored letters or something?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev i assumed that since X was installed on the system, it would launch some sort of window that I could then exit using an escape character like ctrl+c or such. I'm still orienting myself with linux so I'm not too familiar with all the functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to display images in Linux you need the GUI (graphical user interface) to be running, which you've discovered how to start with the `startx` command.

There are however some exceptions! Generally a Raspberry Pi connected directly to a monitor users a *framebuffer console*, which is a high-resolution psuedo-graphics console. If the text isn't massive, you're probably running in framebuffer mode. In this case, you can display images directly using an application that understands the framebuffer. Unfortunately, `display` from imagemagick doesn't appear to do this. However, a tool called `fbi` (short for framebuffer imageviewer) [can show images in framebuffer mode](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2017/02/how-to-display-images-on-raspbian-command-line-with-fbi/).

To use `fbi` to show images in the console, first it needs to be installed. This is done using the package management system commands `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install fbi`. Then, images can be shown full screen using the command `fbi -a myimage.jpg`. Slideshows can be shown using `fbi -a -t 5 *.jpg` where 5 is the number of seconds the image will show for. The [manpage for `fbi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fbi.1.html) has a full description of the command line arguments and is fairly straightforward to read.

Comment: wow, this is awesome, thank you so much for not only a solution but also the links and information about this!!!